# How to align one control to right and a second control to left in a single listview?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to create a chat in listview and I want to add my messages to left and the other side message to right.

like in the following:

[image]

I have created the controls and i want to insert them like in the above layout.

How can this be done?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0):

Every message should be wrapped in a div and based on the message type (e.g. if it is from sender A or sender B) you should set a corresponding css class.

The message itself could have a

```
.messageItem{
 display: inline-block;
 max-width: 200px;
}
```

of course including some more fancy border colors etc. and the wrapper divs

```
.leftWrapper{
  text-align: left;
}
```

..and "right" for ".rightWrapper".

..something like that.